# iOS Mobileconfig for VPN - This profile can only be installed on supervised equipment

Tags: ios

i'm writed mobile config for block ads on iphone throw:
https://gist.github.com/himynameisubik/cbef0e63df468ae5c98386e056ca859d?fbclid=IwAR2vl1NjTz1LUBOL5vyBUjw_euPlS-KCxXOQAgp33x18K_kcAGdv5BSRIxI
but it not work, i received alert:
[alert when i install mobileconfig](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oB2Df.jpg)

this my file:

how to fix it?

Comment: my file: https://github.com/Min9802/VPN

Comment: The `com.apple.proxy.http.global` requires that your device is supervised. You can use [Apple Configurator 2](https://apps.apple.com/au/app/apple-configurator-2/id1037126344?mt=12) to supervise your device (you will need to erase the device). The Giat you linked to something called iSupervisor - presumably this "fakes" the supervision status of your device. Is your device jailbroken?

Comment: my device was jailbreak, and i trying filter web with mobileconfig. and i don't have mac-os then i can't use Apple configurator 2. can i try with web server? Do you know post tutorial with web config ?

Comment: The gist you linked to seems to indicate that you can fake the supervised status, but it isn't too clear. The only way to properly supervise a device is vis Apple Configurator 2 or by having Apple supervise the device at the factory (for enterprise customers). You can't establish supervised state without a USB connection and a mac.

Comment: So how to create a RemoteAddress server like this config, do you have documentation about it?
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Fiinc8gPyrIo2dqNXW-y6s7iSsCBe4lZ/view?fbclid=IwAR3Qm1D9B0vqy-ML5OjaNVQ2ZAz-GYqsjyNBNItM9KI02MQFXNNMYVYGuxs